# No network after installing CM7 on Xperia Arc

Tags: cyanogenmod, sony-xperia-arc, mobile-network

After successfully installing CM7 on Xperia arc by following the steps here, my phone doesn't pick up any network. I looked through the forums and see that some people have reported the same problem. I downloaded the stable image from CM home page for Xperia arc.

After scouring through xda-developer forums I came across this new ROM for arc, does it solve the problem? http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1310313

Also found these in the forums, http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1102523&page=127#1263 which essentially says,

1. Use flashtool to flash baseband_36 (.tft)
2. Use fastboot to flash cm7 custom kernel (boot.img)
3. Use recovery to flash the rom (wipe cache & factory reset then flash the rom)
4. Start your phone and go to apps menu
   chose "Dev tools" -> Bad Behavior -> Crash the system server -> reboot

I am using linux and couldn't make sense of the first step to flash the file.

Any help on solving this problem would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A "baseband" would generally refer to modem firmware.

It seems like the first step is to modify the modem firmware so CM7 can use it.

Does this `flashtool` have a linux binary? (This tool seems to be unique to SE phones, I didn't have to use flashtool to modify HTC phones, only `fastboot`.)

Found Flashtool. [XDA link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=920746) | [Source Code Repository](https://github.com/Androxyde)

Answer (score -1):

You have to re-add the mobile network.  The mobile network site should have the info you need.  Go into Access Points in your mobile system menu.